# Fill table with fetched data after onselect using jquery+ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying fill the table with fetched data from database by the id of selected option. Table content must change when user selects other option. Chosen plugin is working fine and select options is filled with correct values, how to give var selektas from test.php to loader.php in query where kliento_id = $idofclient?
Somehow make selektas == $idofclient so that i could use this variable in query in loader.php

My test.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.chosen-select').chosen();
    }); 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#.pavadinimai").on("change",function(){ 
          var selektas = $(this).val().split('|');
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST", 
                url: "loader.php", 
                data: {selektas[o]}, 
                success: function(result){ 
                    $("#show").html(result); 
                    $('#show').dataTable().fnDestroy(); 
                    $('#show').dataTable();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

    <select class="chosen-select" name="pavname" id="pavadinimai">
        <option selected="selected" value = "">---Pasirinkti---</option>
    <?php

    echo "Pasirinkite klienta"; 
    $sql = "SELECT id, kliento_pav FROM klientai";   
    $stmt = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] .'|'. $row['kliento_pav'] . "'>" . $row['kliento_pav'] . "</option>";
    } 
    list($idofclient,$pavofclient) = explode ('|',$_POST['pavname']); 
?>
</select>
<div id="show">
     </div>
```

And this is my code in loader.php

```
<?php  
require_once "config.php";
if(isset($_POST["pavadinimas"])){  
    $sql_query="SELECT uzsakymai.id, kliento_id, uzsakymai.kiekis,prekes.pavadinimas,uzsakymai.aprasymas FROM uzsakymai INNER JOIN prekes ON uzsakymai.prekes_id = prekes.id INNER JOIN klientai on uzsakymai.kliento_id = klientai.id WHERE kliento_id = $idofclient"
    $resultset = mysqli_query($link, $sql_query) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($link));              
    while( $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
?>
<br>
<table id="data_table" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Prekės pavadinimas</th>
            <th>Kiekis</th>
            <th>Aprašymas</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="<?php echo $result ['id']; ?>">
            <td><?php echo $result ['pavadinimas']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result ['kiekis']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result ['aprasymas']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php
 echo $result
 }
 ?>
```

I'm using ...jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Initially you initialized the table so first clear that table
$('#myTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
Then initialize again after ajax success
$('#myTable').dataTable();
Like this.....

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#.pavadinimai").on("change",function(){ 
  $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "loader.php", 
    data: {$idofclient}, 
    success: function(result){ 
      $("#show").html(result); 
     $('#show').dataTable().fnDestroy();
     $('#show').dataTable();
    }
  });
});
```

});

Comment: why not destroy the data table before you send the new data?

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pavadinimai").on("change", function() {
    var pavadinimai = $("#pavadinimai").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "loader.php",
      data: {
        pavadinimai: pavadinimai
      },
      success: function(result) {
        $("#show").html(result);
        $('#show').dataTable().fnDestroy();
        $('#show').dataTable();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Please use id as selector instead of using both id class. Also create variable and assigned with the value from select input and post it via the ajax data method

Comment: Still my data is not showing, i select option but nothing happens, not even error

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: well that doesn't help because i said before my code does nothing it should do. I need help to identify why my code gives no result. In my vision after i select one of the selections it should give results from database to the page. After i select something, nothing happens, i don't even get error so i can't indentify the mistake i made, tha't why i'm asking for help, thankyou.